# Finding the Percentage from a grep variable

Tags: shell-script, variable, uptime

I want to display the calculation of the CPU load in percentage.

```
num2=$(uptime | grep "average:" | tr -d " " | cut -d ':' -f 5 | cut -d ',' -f 2)

percent=$((num2(*100)))
echo 'CPU percentage' $percent
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is that an actual typo of `(*100)` or a copy/paste typo?

Comment: Nope that's what I think how it should be.

Comment: bash arithmetic uses infix notation, so you'd need `$((num2 * 100))`, if that's all that's stopping you

Comment: it always shows up a syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".01")

Comment: That seems like an awfully long pipeline - at least on Linux, you might want to look at reading the value more directly from `/proc/loadavg` e.g. `awk '{print "CPU percentage " $2*100}' < /proc/loadavg`

Comment: Thx @steeldriver this helped a lot. Can I use the same method to find the percentage of free memory.

Comment: The load average is not a percentage. It's the average length of the run queue over a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `num2` value will be something like `0.41`.  `bash` can do integer calculations only, no floating. That's why we get an eror msg like

```
bash: 0.41 * 100 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".41 * 100 ")
```

Try removing the dots when using your `tr -d` statement. That would be equivalent to a multiplication by 100.

Comment: This should be a comment. An answer should explain how to solve the problem, not just the reason for the error.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. Added a proposal to circumnavigate the error.

Comment: What dots in the `tr -d` command? Show the command he should be writing instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe your calculation for `percent` into `bc`.

```
percent=$(echo "scale=0;$num2*100" | bc)
```

It'll give you a number like "41.00" you can cut that off the end with

```
percent=${percent%.*}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider one simple `awk` command:

```
uptime | awk '/average/ {printf "CPU percentage %5.2f", $11*100}'
```